# Effective way to tell what ids in a set of ids are still in the database (I.e intersect input ids with collection ids) MongoDb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection with around 80 million documents. 
Via an API the user can validate if a set of ids (input-set) are still present in the database. 
The input set can be rather large, but I would split the validation into chunks of approx. 10000 ids. 
Basically I would like to get the intersection between the database ids and the input-set.

I'd like to do this with Linq but other suggestions are welcome.

Below is some sample code that shows my scenario and what I have tried so far.

The first approach is what I would do but it throws an NotSupportedException : The method Intersect is not supported in the expression tree:

The second approach works but is really slow on large sets.

The third approach is faster than the second but then I have to load 80 million ids in memory.

We have tried to stick with the linq interface provided by the C# wrapper but it is a struggle sometimes. Any pointers are appreciated. I guess there's a way forward using different builders and pipeline defintion with $setIntersection but I can not get my head around the c# documentation on that.

```
  private string[] FilterOnExistInDatabase1(string[] candidates)
    {
        // Query<T> is just a wrapper to the collection and returns a IQueryable<T>
        return mongoRepository.Query<TestModel>().Select(x => x.Id).Intersect(candidates).ToArray();
    }

    private string[] FilterOnExistInDatabase2(string[] candidates)
    {
        // Query<T> is just a wrapper to the collection and returns a IQueryable<T>
        return mongoRepository.Query<TestModel>().Select(x => x.Id).Where(x => candidates.Contains(x)).ToArray();
    }

    private string[] FilterOnExistInDatabase3(string[] candidates)
    {
        // Query<T> is just a wrapper to the collection and returns a IQueryable<T>
        var allExistingIds = mongoRepository.Query<TestModel>().Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
        var existingCandidates = allExistingIds.Intersect(candidates).ToArray();
        return existingCandidates;
    }

    [Test]
    public void SampleQuery()
    {
        var models = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new TestModel()).ToArray();
        mongoRepository.InsertMany(models, CancellationToken.None);

        var deletedId = "I no longer exist";
        var candidates = models.Select(x => x.Id).Concat(new []{deletedId}).ToArray();
        var existingCandidates = FilterOnExistInDatabase3(candidates);

        Assert.That(existingCandidates.Length, Is.EqualTo(models.Length));
        Assert.False(existingCandidates.Contains(deletedId));
        Assert.That(existingCandidates.Length, Is.EqualTo(candidates.Length - 1));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

how about the following approach? basically you get back an array of IDs that exist in the db and produce the intersection on the client-side using linq to get the invalid/deleted IDs.

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Item : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            var one = new Item { Name = "one" }; one.Save();
            var two = new Item { Name = "two" }; two.Save();
            var thr = new Item { Name = "three" }; thr.Save();

            var inputIDs = new[] { one.ID, two.ID, ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString() };

            var validIDs = DB.Queryable<Item>() // for official driver use: collection.AsQueryable()
                             .Where(i => inputIDs.Contains(i.ID))
                             .Select(i => i.ID)
                             .ToArray();

            var deletedIDs = inputIDs.Except(validIDs).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

this should theoritically be faster than your second method above because it doesn't cause a projection of every ID in the collection. if this approach is acceptable for you, i'd be interested in knowing how many milliseconds it takes mongodb to finish this task for 80 million docs.